# Set alignment in`split`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, split, alignment

I want to state a linear programming problem in the conventional manner. The following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setstretch{1.8}
    (LP)
    \begin{cases}
    \begin{split}
        \max \qquad &\sum_{\{i|(i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,e}\\ \\
        \text{ subject to}\qquad &\sum_{\{i|(i,k)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,k} = \sum_{\{j|(k,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{k,j} & \forall k\in(\mathcal{N}\setminus\{s,e\})\\
        &\sum_{\{j|(s,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{s,j} = \sum_{\{i|(i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,e}\\
        &0 \le x_{i,j} \le b_{i,j} &\raggedleft \forall(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}
    \end{split}
    \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: lp formulation]

Is there a way to make the `\forall` quantificators align to the left instead of  to the right? I.e., i want them to be aligned by the first character, not the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
(LP)\left\{
    \begin{array}{r@{\qquad}c>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}ll}
\max
    &&\sum_{\{i|(i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,e}           &   &   \\[5ex]
\text{subject to}
    &&\sum_{\{i|(i,k)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,k}
        & = \sum_{\{j|(k,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{k,j}
            &\quad \forall k\in(\mathcal{N}\setminus\{s,e\})\\
    &&\sum_{\{j|(s,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{s,j}
        & = \sum_{\{i|(i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,e}        &   \\
    &&0 \le x_{i,j} \le b_{i,j}
        &   &\quad \forall(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

with use `mathrlap` from the package `mathtools` you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.8}
(LP)\left\{
    \begin{array}{r@{\quad}c>{\displaystyle}r>{\displaystyle}ll}
\max
    &&\sum_{\{i|(i,e)\mathrlap{\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{i,e}           &   &   \\[5ex]
\text{subject to}
    &&\sum_{\{i|(i,k)\mathrlap{\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{i,k}
        & = \sum_{\{j|(k,j)\mathrlap{\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{k,j}
            &\quad \forall k\in(\mathcal{N}\setminus\{s,e\})\\
    &&\sum_{\{j|(s,j)\mathrlap{\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{s,j}
        & = \sum_{\{i|(i,e)\mathrlap{\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{i,e}        &   \\
    &&  0 \le x_{i,j} \le b_{i,j}
        &   &   \quad \forall(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}
    \end{array}
    \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll show you a trick that avoids abusing `setspace`.

The `aligned` environment increases the interline spacing by a dimension that's called `jot`. Its default value is 3pt, but one can locally set it to a different one.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\jot}{1.5ex} % some more vertical space
(LP)
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
  \max \quad &\! \sum_{\{i|(i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,e}\\[2ex]
  \text{ subject to}\quad
  &\! \sum_{\{i\mid(i,k)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,k} =
      \sum_{\{j\mid(k,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{k,j}
  &&  \forall k\in(\mathcal{N}\setminus\{s,e\})\\
  &\! \sum_{\{j\mid(s,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{s,j} =
      \sum_{\{i\mid(i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}} x_{i,e}\\
  &   0 \le x_{i,j} \le b_{i,j}
  && \forall(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some notes.

The vertical bar should be called `\mid`, which is a relation symbol; the output is the same, in the case at hand, but using the right semantics is important.

Between `&` and `\sum` there should be a negative thin space, because in even numbered columns `amsmath` implicitly adds `{}` that causes a thin space to be inserted if an operator follows and, in this particular case we don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this alignment, with `alignedat`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[ \setstretch{1.8}
    (LP)
    \begin{cases}
    \begin{alignedat}{2}
 \max \quad\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\{i\mid (i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{i,e} & \phantom{ =}\\[1ex]%\\
        \text{ subject to} \quad\smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\{i\mid (i,k)\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{i,k} & = \smashoperator{\sum_{\{j\mid (k,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{k,j} &\qquad & \forall k\in(\mathcal{N}\setminus\{s,e\})\\
        \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{\{j\mid (s,j)\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{s,j} & = \smashoperator{\sum_{\{i\mid (i,e)\in\mathcal{A}\}}} x_{i,e}\\
        0 \le x_{i,j} & \le b_{i,j} & & \forall(i,j)\in\mathcal{A}
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I fiercely object to the abuse of `setspace`. Ever heard about `\openup`?

Comment: No, but I plead ‘not guilty’ – `\setspace` was in the O.P.'s code, and I didn't touch it. What's `\openup`?

Comment: Your bag of tricks is almost empty. `;-)`

Comment: I mainly know a small number of packages which enable me to do more or less what I want, but I'm in no way a (La)TeX guru. Nevertheless I'm delighted when I can learn new tricks. I'll google about this command!

Comment: Mmmhh… There is no guarantee that the right edges of “max” and of “subject to” will be vertically aligned.

Comment: @GuM: I played with the fact that all sums have the same structure.